# Как получить доступ к корневому элементу из листа в листе JSON

Tags: java, json, jasperreports

Есть JSON файл такой структуры:

```
{
"person" {
    "someElement" : "test", 
    "operationsList": [
        {
          "date": 1505980686916,
          "sendersLastName": "last",
          "sendersFirstName": "first",
          "sendersSecondName": "second",
          "operationDetailsList" : [
            {
                "innerKey" : "key1",
                "innerValue" : "value1"
            },
            {
                "innerKey" : "key2",
                "innerValue" : "value2"
            }
          ],
          "operationCurrencyAmount": 456,
          "operationCurrencyCode": "TEST"
        },
        {
          "date": 1505980686916,
          "sendersLastName": "last",
          "sendersFirstName": "first",
          "sendersSecondName": "second",
          "operationDetailsList" : [
            {
                "innerKey" : "key1",
                "innerValue" : "value1"
            },
            {
                "innerKey" : "key2",
                "innerValue" : "value2"
            }
          ],
          "operationCurrencyAmount": 456,
          "operationCurrencyCode": "TEST"
        },          

    ],
    "otherField" : "testValue"      
},
"booleanFlag" : true
}
```

Создан jr:list с элементами "operationsList":
**subDataSource("person.operationsList")**.

Внутри этого (operationsList) листа есть еще один jr:list **(operationDetailsList):
subDataSource("operationDetailsList")**

***Вопрос:*** 
Нужно внутри дочернего (operationDetailsList) листа использовать корневой элемент "booleanFlag" в качестве printWhenExpression для одного из полей (например, "innerKey"). 
Однако в списке доступных полей есть только поля из subDataset="operationDetailsList", т.е. доступны только "innerKey" и "innerValue". Можно ли получить доступ к элементу "booleanFlag" из листа в листе?

Comment: сначала надо распарсить json, а затем получить доступ к его элементам.

Comment: Как вариант делать дополнительный объект с параметром в виде этого флага и по окончанию парса JSON строки внедрять этот объект в мапу вида map<JsonObject, SomeFlagObject>. Или куда проще делать map<JsonObject, List<Object>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть решение, можно передать это поле в виде параметра в лист и использовать в листе именно параметр, а не сам филд.